# String concatenation as an alias displays 0 in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, alias

I was looking at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) tutorial from W3Schools, where they combine address, zip code and country together as a single column "Address". So I've been playing with the Northwind DB and wanted to do the same thing for employee name:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName +" "+ LastName AS Name FROM Employees;
```

But all I get is 0's in the "Name" column. I figure SQLite has implicitly converted the string to integer, but it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace + with || wich is the string concatenation operator in SQLite and many other databases.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName || ', ' || LastName AS Name FROM Employees;
```